# Access data of a main table from a subtable

Tags: powerquery

I have a table containing a column with paths and the others one with tables

My goal is to add the path to all the tables in the 2nd column, here is an example of what I want to achieve (Originally Table1 and Table2 doesn't have the path column and I want to add it):

| Path | Data |
| --- | --- |
| C:/My/Path | [Table1] |
| C:/My/Second/Path | [Table2] |

In Table1:

| Data | Path |
| --- | --- |
| SomeData | C:/My/Path |
| SomeOtherData | C:/My/Path |

In Table2:

| Data | Path |
| --- | --- |
| MoreData | C:/My/Second/Path |

I tried to use AddColumn in my subtable but I don't know how to access the data of the main table from there:

```
= Table.AddColumn(Query1, "Custom", each Table.AddColumn([Data], "Path", each [Path]))
// Doesn't work because I can't access [Path] which is from the main table in the subtable
```

So how can I access the data from my main table to add it to my subtable?

Comment: If you just expand your column of tables **Data**, won't that give you what you want?

Comment: I think the column isn't currently there and they want to add it to the nested table. I.e.they're showing expected output

Comment: Indeed, as @David said the "Path" column in Table1 and Table2 isn't there and my goal is to have it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
= Table.AddColumn(
        #"Renamed Columns", 
        "New", 
        (o)=>Table.AddColumn(
                o[Data], 
                "Path",
                each o[Path],
                type text
                ),
        type table
    )
```